# Is there a way to force a native thread to exit through JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, ffmpeg

I have a program that's using the FFMPEG binary libraries via JNI.  There is a call to open a URL which is blocking in native code, and I need to allow the user to manually cancel this connection.  Sometimes Thread.interrupt() works just like it's supposed to (if the url I'm connecting to is "udp://{whatever}").  If my URL is "rtp://{whatever}", Thread.interrupt() doesn't appear to be honored by the native thread.  Thread.kill() doesn't even seem to do it (and is generally frowned on anyhow).

Does anyone know a different way to interrupt or kill a native thread through JNI?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think this is related to a (somewhat old) FFMPEG bug: https://roundup.ffmpeg.org/issue539

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native code can regularly check the thread to see if it's interrupted, just as Java code does.

Another approach is operating-system-specific, but you can send you thread a signal and that signal can set a flag - this may be more straightforward for the JNI-side to check.

All thread-stopping is cooperative - you tell the thread to stop by setting a flag (via `Thread.interrupt()` or a flag set in a signal handler - and the thread code checks this often.

Comment: I'm using FFMPEG as a native library, and I'd REALLY like to avoid changing the native side if at all possible - if it's unchanged I can just use the pre-built binaries rather than having to recompile it myself for every target platform.

I'm a bit of a JNI newbie, is there a way to send a signal to a thread from the Java side (other than interrupt), in hopes that there's something that the native side IS actually checking for?

Comment: you can't litter your FFMPEG code with checks but you can check in the JNI code that calls the avcodec avformat bits per frame?

Comment: If I was in the frame processing loop, I could, but my thread is blocking trying to open the URL in the first place (I'm worried about the case where a user has mistyped the URL, and wants to free up the resources because they're NEVER going to receive any data there).  It appears to be the call to av_open_input_file in libavformat/utils.c that's blocking and not being interrupted properly.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at how [Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) does this (a JNI wapper to FFmpeg).  Everytime FFmpeg calls it's interrupt callback, Xuggler calls into Java to see if the thread was interrupted, and if so, returns true.

Comment: Lol!  I'm actually already using Xuggle.  This question is effectively a duplicate of a post I eventually made on the Xuggle forums: http://groups.google.com/group/xuggler-users/browse_thread/thread/30d73c1b1a6bb95c

Thanks, though!